# Script works only on homepage

Tags: javascript, joomla, conflict

I have problem with adding class after scroll and it's really strange to me and here is why:

I used this script on multiple projects and never had this problem before. When I scroll down on home page, script works perefectly, class "Fix" is added to class "navigacija" and the social icons, menu and languages are fixed at top of the page. But on other pages this is not the case. Class "Fix" isn't added to class "navigacija" after scrolling 145px down. And what's more interesting, I insert very large image on purpose at [this page](http://investfarm.moderanweb.rs/o-kompaniji) and until page loads that image, my script works (try to scroll down before image is loaded). When page is fully loaded, script doesn't work anymore. I'm working in Joomla, I made my own template, I didn't install any modules, components or plugins. There are only Joomla's standard js files and my scripts that I used before with this script without any problem.

Here is the website I'm working on: http://investfarm.moderanweb.rs/

and here is the script:

```
$(function() {
    var navigacija = $(".navigacija");
    $(window).scroll(function() {    
        var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

        if (scroll >= 145) {
            navigacija.removeClass('navigacija').addClass("Fix");
        } else {
            navigacija.removeClass("Fix").addClass('navigacija');
        }
    });
});
```

Please help, thanks in advance.

Comment: In your second page, it seems like there is a conflict using `$`, if you are using jQueryNoConflict you should change `$` to `jQuery` or Am I wrong !

Comment: Multiple errors in the console.  First thing you should do is understand those errors.

Comment: As it stands, you have 2 versions of jQuery being loaded on your site along with trying to load a 3rd version (which isn't working as stated by @jfriend00). Loading multiple instances of jQuery can result in conflicts

Answer (score 0):

For starters, start cleaning up the errors that show in the console.

You have multiple script tags that points to an HTML page not to a script.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/templates/investfarmimpexmd/js/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/templates/investfarmimpexmd/js/wow.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/wow.min.js"></script>
```

I don't know what you expected those to be loading, but it is not loading a script and is causing errors.

Perhaps these be marked `type="text/template"` so the browser doesn't try to execute them and you can use them as templates?

---

And, you have an error on this line of inline Javascript that indicates that jQuery is not loaded properly so you will have to find out why that is:

```
 jQuery(window).on('load',  function() {
     new JCaption('img.caption');
 });
```

---

And, you are loading multiple different versions of jQuery in the same page, but not managing how those different versions are used.  You can't just load a version of jQuery, issue a `jQuery.noConflict()` and then load another version of jQuery.  The first will be doing nothing at that point so if you needed it for something, it will not be working.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change `$` to `jQuery` if you are using jQueryNoConflict, and why is it working on homepage, I guess because jQuery library is loaded twice, before and after mootools library, so try this instead, and you should do the same for `ToolTip` and other stuffs :

```
jQuery(function() {
    var navigacija = $(".navigacija");
    jQuery(window).scroll(function() {    
        var scroll = jQuery(window).scrollTop();

        if (scroll >= 145) {
            navigacija.removeClass('navigacija').addClass("Fix");
        } else {
            navigacija.removeClass("Fix").addClass('navigacija');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: This solved my problem. Thank you! And thanks everyone for quick replies. I'll try to figure out what console telling me